# I want that the next element of the li should not be allowed to click if last one has not been clicked and want to show clicked li active

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="panel-body" id="social">
        <ul id="gallery" class="list-group">

            @if (Model != null)
        {

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <li class="list-group-item"><a id="myreflink" href="@item.Link" onclick="@item.Link" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">@item.LinkName</a></li>

            }
        }

        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var selector = '#gallery li';

            $(selector).on('click', function () {
                $(selector).removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What I need is next li element should not be allowed to click if user has not clicked the next element and show active class to the clicked element. I am using above code to show active class but when the page is getting loaded the active class fades. Good answers will be appreciated.

Comment: it disappears because on load, it gets the new data from your model, then redraw it.
If you want the data to persist. I suggest make an ajax call and save a trigger that the current row is active.

Comment: Ok,Will try this.Thanks @Josh